# Coefficients of glm

Tags: r

I have a question about the glm function.

When I set

```
m= glm(outcome ~ predictor, family = "binomial")

c1 = m$coefficients[1]

c2 = m$coefficients[2]
```

How can c1 and c2 be interpreted?
I‘d like to set up a regression function describing the data with these coefficients, but I don’t know the general function to plug them in.

Comment: Welcome to SO! For statistics questions, better have a look there: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `glm` with `family` set to `binomial` then I'm guessing `outcome` is a *binary* variable, in which case you are carrying out a *logistic regression*.

The coefficients of a logistic regression can be thought of as log odds. If the intercept is 0, then this means that at the intercept, the odds of the outcome occurring is exp(0), which is 1.

Remember that the odds of an event happening is the ratio of the probability of the event happening to the probability of it not happening. Therefore if the *odds* of the outcome is 1, the *probability* of the outcome is 0.5.

It's maybe better if we show this using some sample data we create ourselves using a random sample where we specify the probability of the outcome, and see if we can recover these probabilities from our model.

We will create a data frame with a two-level factor variable called `predictor`, containing the groups "A" and "B", where the probability of the outcome is 0.5 in group "A", and 0.67 in group "B":

```r
set.seed(123
df <- data.frame(outcome   = c(rbinom(1000, 1, 1/2), rbinom(1000, 1, 2/3)),
                 predictor = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 1000))
```

And now we can create out model:

```r
my_model <- glm(outcome ~ predictor, data = df, family = binomial)

coef(my_model)
#> (Intercept)  predictorB 
#> -0.02800183  0.79098010
```

This means that the log odds of the outcome in group "A" is -0.028, and the log odds of the outcome in group B is -0.28 + 0.79. We can therefore get the actual odds of the outcome by taking the exponent of these values:

```
odds_of_outcome_given_A <- exp(coef(my_model))[1]
odds_of_outcome_given_B <- exp(sum(coef(my_model)))
```

This simple function can now convert odds to probabilities for us:

```
probability_from_odds <- function(o) o/(o + 1)
```

So we can do:

```
probability_of_outcome_given_A <- probability_from_odds(odds_of_outcome_given_A)
probability_of_outcome_given_B <- probability_from_odds(odds_of_outcome_given_B)
```

Which gives us our estimates of the probabilities of our initial sample:

```
probability_of_outcome_given_A
#> (Intercept) 
#>       0.493
probability_of_outcome_given_B
#> [1] 0.682
```

You can see that these are very close to the 0.5 and 0.667 we gave to our binomial sample at the start.

<sup>Created on 2020-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>